# How to apply 'OR' operator between claims of a policy

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, authorization

Maybe my question is not well stated, but I'd like to know how to create a Blazor authorization policy that is valid if the user satisfies at least 1 of its claims, rather than having to satisfy all claims specified in the policy.

My code is currently like that :

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
            options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;

            options.AddPolicy("AdminsAndMods", policy =>
            {
                policy.RequireClaim("Admin", "true");
                //policy.RequireClaim("Moderator", "true"); // I want the policy to be valid for admins and for moderators
            });
        });
```

If I uncheck the second "RequireClaim" in the code, it will require the user to be both admin and moderator, but I want the user to be validated against the policy if he has at least 1 of the two claims.

I know that I could use Roles instead, and that roles can be combined inside an <AuthorizeView> or [Authorize], but I must not use them.

Comment: You could add a claim to both roles and the policy check for the claim...

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an `IAuthorizationRequirement` which implements multiple `AuthorizationHandler`s.

A requirement succeeds if any of the handlers succeed.

```cs
// The requirement
public class AdminOrModeratorAuthorizationRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }

// Two Handlers for the requirement
public class AdminAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AdminOrModeratorAuthorizationRequirement, null>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AdminOrModeratorAuthorizationRequirement requirement, object? data)
    {
        if (context.User.IsInRole(AppPolicies.AdminRole))
            context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class ModeratorAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AdminOrModeratorAuthorizationRequirement, null>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AdminOrModeratorAuthorizationRequirement requirement, object? data)
    {
        if (context.User.IsInRole(AppPolicies.ModeratorRole))
            context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

You can then define a policy.  I've encapsulated everything within a static `AppPolicies` class.

```cs
public static class AppPolicies
{
    public const string AdminRole = "AdminRole";
    public const string ModeratorRole = "ModeratorRole";
    //...

    public const string IsAdminOrModeratorPolicy = "IsAdminOrModeratorPolicy";
    //...

    public static AuthorizationPolicy IsAdminOrModeratorAuthorizationPolicy
        => new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddRequirements(new AdminOrModeratorAuthorizationRequirement())
        .Build();

    public static Dictionary<string, AuthorizationPolicy> Policies
    {
        get
        {
            var policies = new Dictionary<string, AuthorizationPolicy>();

            policies.Add(IsAdminOrModeratorPolicy, IsAdminOrModeratorAuthorizationPolicy);
            //...
            return policies;
        }
    }

    public static void AddAppPolicyServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AdminAuthorizationHandler>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ModeratorAuthorizationHandler>();

        //..
    }
```

And add the services

```cs
         // Your AuthenticationStateProvider
        services.AddAppPolicyServices();
        services.AddAuthorization(config =>
        {
            foreach (var policy in AppPolicies.Policies)
            {
                config.AddPolicy(policy.Key, policy.Value);
            }
        });
```

Hope it all works, I have no way to test it.

There's a set of documentation [from which this answer is based] and working example based on Weather in a Repo here: https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.Authorization.

The MS documentation on this topic is here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0